# Python - Check if IPv6 address falls in range

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for the best way to check a line in a lease file to see if an IPv6 address falls into a range:

i.e. 2603:7300:201:2::50 - 2603:7300:201:2::ffff

Something like:

possible pseudo-code in asterisks

```
for line in file:
    if *denote last set of ip* > *denote last set of range low (i.e. 50)* and < *denote last set of range high*:
        do something
```

Essentially my hang up is how to go about referencing the last set in the IP address for the checks. Any help or a nudge to a resource greatly appreciated!

Comment: `def check_ip(addr):
last_part = int(addr.split(&amp;#39;:&amp;#39;)[-1], 16);
return 50 <= last_part and last_part <= 65535`

Comment: Thanks for response but I am confused with the syntax of your code and am indeed getting a syntax error when I test it. Can you elaborate on the content of addr.split for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: I have used your addr.split method and adjusted it a bit to work for my situation but it is working now. Thanks for showing me this method it will come in handy as I work with Python more.

Comment: This will help:
`def check_ip(addr):
        last_part = int(addr.split(':')[-1], 16);
        return 50 <= last_part and last_part <= 65535;
`